# R: Convert variable name to string in sapply

Tags: r

I have found that to convert a variable name into a string I would use `deparse(substitute(x))` where `x` is my variable name.  But what if I want to do this in an sapply function call?

```
sapply( myDF, function(x) { hist( x, main=VariableNameAsString ) } )
```

When I use `deparse(substitute(x))`, I get something like `X[[1L]]` as the title.  I would like to have the actual variable name.  Any help would be appreciated.

David

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need the names, then iterate over the names, not the values:

```
sapply(names(myDF), function(nm) hist(myDF[[nm]], main=nm))
```

Alternatively, iterate over both names and values at the same time using `mapply` or `Map`:

```
Map(function(name, values) hist(values, main=name),
    names(myDF), myDF)
```

For the most part, you shouldn't be using `deparse` and `substitute` unless you are doing metaprogramming (if you don't know what it is, you're not doing it).

Comment: Yep. When using `sapply`, values are being passed without names.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a piece of code that worked for me:

`deparse(substitute(variable))`